# Underscore template not rendering in backbone

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js

I'm trying out a simple example (see full code below) with the latest production versions of backbone.js, underscore.js and jquery.
However I can't get anything displayed on the screen. I have tried logging this.$el to console log and it seems valid, also the html var contains the correct parsed HTML from the test-template. But nothing is shown in the browser window.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>testing Backbone.js</title>
  </head>
  <body>

      <script type="text/template" id="test-template">
      <div id="container">
          <%= test %>
      </div>
      </script>

      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/jquery.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/underscore.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/backbone.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        var testView = Backbone.View.extend({
            el: $("#container"),
            template: _.template($('#test-template').html()),
            render: function() {
                var html = this.template({test: 'hello World!'});
                this.$el.html(html);
                return this;
            }
        });

        $(document).ready(function() {
            var test = new testView();
            test.render();
        });
      </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no element with id="container" to append the template to.  If you replace

```
el: $("#container")
```

with

```
el: $('body')
```

Something should show up

Answer (score 1):

There is no render code . Template's content not the  visuable part of DOM;
try this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>testing Backbone.js</title>
  </head>
  <body>
      <div id="output"></div>
      <script type="text/template" id="test-template">
      <div id="container">
          <%= test %>
      </div>
      </script>

      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/jquery.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/underscore.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/backbone.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        var testView = Backbone.View.extend({
            el: $("#container"),
            template: _.template($('#test-template').html()),
            render: function() {
                var html = this.template({test: 'hello World!'});
                $("#output").html(html);
                return this;
            }
        });

    $(document).ready(function() {
        var test = new testView();
        test.render();
    });
  </script>
```